# Android Studio - parameters name when invoking methods

Tags: android

When automatically invoking methods for a seekbar (for example), the names of the parameters are not user friendly. i for int, b for boolean instead of progress and fromUser

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
   tvMinutes.setText(String.valueOf(i) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.minutes));
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change their names to understand them better, probably?

Comment: Then Change them!!

Comment: change it to understand

Comment: My question is why are they automatically generated this way instead of their real names and how can I make it generated correctly